# User names and passwords are logged in plain text during initialization of Atomikos

Tags: java, jdbc, jta, xa, atomikos

Our project relies on Atomikos to provide light-weight transaction management. However, we find that it logs the DB user name and password in plain text during initialization.

E.g.

```
2015-10-15 16:43:01,106 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] INFO  com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean  - AtomikosDataSoureBean 'LAB_Oracle': initializing with [ xaDataSourceClassName=oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource, uniqueResourceName=LAB_Oracle, maxPoolSize=8, minPoolSize=1, borrowConnectionTimeout=30, maxIdleTime=60, reapTimeout=0, maintenanceInterval=60, testQuery=null, xaProperties=[URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@***:1537:oocait01,user=***,password=**] loginTimeout=0]
```

Is there any configuration that can suppress the logging of these confidential information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as configuration, you can set your threshold to `WARN` for log category `com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean`. There are some examples for popular logging frameworks [here](http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/ConfiguringTheLogs). That would filter out that entire message.

If you only want to filter the confidential properties, you could create a subclass of [`AtomikosDataSourceBean`](https://github.com/atomikos/transactions-essentials/blob/master/public/transactions-jdbc/src/main/java/com/atomikos/jdbc/AtomikosDataSourceBean.java) and override the protected method `printXaProperties()`. Then you can filter out any confidential properties such as passwords.

```
package my.com.atomikos.jdbc;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;

public class AtomikosDataSourceBean extends com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected String printXaProperties()
    {
        Properties xaProperties = getXaProperties();
        StringBuffer ret = new StringBuffer();
        if ( xaProperties != null ) {
            Enumeration it = xaProperties.propertyNames();
            ret.append ( "[" );
            boolean first = true;
            while ( it.hasMoreElements() ) {
                String name = ( String ) it.nextElement();
                if ( name.equals ( "password" ) ) continue;
                if ( ! first ) ret.append ( "," );
                String value = xaProperties.getProperty( name );
                ret.append ( name ); ret.append ( "=" ); ret.append ( value );
                first = false;
            }
            ret.append ( "]" );
        }
        return ret.toString();
    }
}
```

Since Atomikos will automatically detect the logging framework, which could vary depending how you test, package and deploy your application, using a subclass is probably more foolproof.

I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/atomikos/transactions-essentials/pull/3) that could make it into version 4. We'll see.